Android Studio Emulator, thats started from CLI, crashes when trying to click on sidebar
When Emulator is started from Android Studio(./studio.sh), Sidebar works fine.
When Emulator is started from CLI, it crashes when clicking on sidebar.
Important: i need writeable system, thats why i have to start from CLI
The command i normally use to start the emulator:
emulator -avd Pixel_6_Pro_API_28 -writable-system -no-snapshot
(it crashes also when only using "emulator -avd Pixel_6_Pro_API_28" as command)
press on Sidebar,this shows up, emulator crashes completly:
INFO    | Info: Sandboxing disabled by user. ((null):0, (null))
Segmentation fault
More Details Here:
emulator -avd Pixel_6_Pro_API_28 -writable-system -no-snapshot -verbose Output
